# Scanf seems to be working incorrectly, or I am doing something wrong

Tags: c, scanf

So I am trying to do a simple program finding the greatest common denominator of any two values, but it keeps giving me this error message,

"xxx.exe has stopped working. A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available."

and crashes my program. I am thoroughly confused, if you have any input, please help!

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
int first, second;

//Scans in variables
printf("What numbers would you like to find the GCD of?\n");
scanf("%d%d",&first,&second);

int gcd = (first%second);
//Loop
while (gcd !=0)
    {
    first = second;
    second = (first%second);
    gcd = (first%second);
    }
//Prints output
printf("Your GCD is: %d", second);
return 0;
}
```

As problems with `scanf` are the only times I have ever seen this error message before, I have tried changing the

```
scanf("%d%d", &first, &second);
```

to a variety of things, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Use the debugger and step through your code to see what's happening, where you can inspect the values of the variables. What does that tell you?

Comment: this line: scanf("%d%d",&first,&second); fails to allow any kind of separation between the numbers, so only one 'long' number will be read in.  You should check the return value from scanf() to assure that the correct number of values are set.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting `divide by zero` error

After 2nd statement below second variable will be zero as  first and second are holding same number
so 3rd statement gives divide by zero

```
first = second;
second = (first%second);
gcd = (first%second);
```

Here is a way to calculate GCD

```
int 
gcd ( int a, int b )
{
  int c;
  while ( a != 0 ) {
     c = a; a = b%a;  b = c;
  }
  return b;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with the `scanf` function. I think the following code caused the issue:

```
...
first = second             // now first equals second
second = (first % second)  // now second is 0
gcd = (first % second)     // mod 0, Arithmetic Exception thrown out here
...
```

The issue is you mod 0 which is just like divide a number by 0. If this is not obvious to you, you can use a debugger to verify this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is a scanf issue. If second is 0, your program will crash.